# Random email addresses being signed up to my website

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention

Over the past few months random email addresses, some of which are on known spam lists, have been added at the rate of 2 or 3 a day to my website.

I know they aren't real humans - for a start the website is in a very narrow geographical area, and many of these emails are clearly from a different country, others are info@ addresses that appear to have been harvested from a website, rather than something a human would use to sign up to a site.

What I can't work out is, what are reasons for somebody doing this? I can't see any benefit to an external party beyond being vaguely destructive. (I don't want to link to the site here, it's just a textbox where you enter email and press join).

These emails are never verified - my question isn't about how to prevent this, but what are some valid reasons why somebody might do this. I think it's important to understand why malicious users do what they do.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a **list bombing attack**, which is definitely not valid. The only valid use I can think of is for **security research**, and that's a corner case.

### List bomb

I suspect this is part of a [list bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_bomb#List_linking) attack, which is when somebody uses a tool or service to maliciously sign up a victim for as much junk email as possible. I work in anti-spam and have seen victims' perspectives on this: it's nearly all opt-in verifications, meaning the damage is only one per service. It sounds like you're in the [Confirmed Opt-In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opt-in_email#Confirmed_opt-in_(COI)/Double_opt-in_(DOI)) (COI) camp, so congratulations, it could be worse.

We don't have good solutions for list bombing. There are too many problems to entertain a global database of hashed emails that have recently opted into lists (so list maintainers could look up an address, conclude it's being bombed, and refuse to invite). A global database of hashed emails opting *out* of bulk mail (like the US [Do Not Call list](https://www.donotcall.gov) or the now-defunct [Blue Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Frog)'s [Do Not Intrude registry](https://www.theinternetpatrol.com/blue-frog-blue-security-brings-us-yet-another-abusive-ddos-anti-spam-program/) but without the controversial DDoS-the-spammers portion) could theoretically work in this capacity, though there'd still be a lot of hurdles to clear.

At the moment, the best thing you can do is to rate-limit (which this attacker is savvy enough to avoid) and use captchas. You can measure your success based on the click rate of the links in your COI emails; if it's still low, you still have a problem.

In your particular case, asking the user to identify a region via drop-down, with no default, may give you an easy way to reject subscriptions or trigger more complex captchas.

If you're interested in a more research-driven approach, you could try to fingerprint the subscription requests and see if you can identify the tool (if it's client-run, and I believe most are) or the service (if it's cloud-run, in which case you can hopefully just blacklist a few CIDR ranges instead). Pay attention to requesters' HTTP headers, especially the referer. Browser fingerprinting it its own arms race; take a gander at the EFF's [Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/) or Brian Kreb's piece on [AntiDetect](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/03/antidetect-helps-thieves-hide-digital-fingerprints/).

### Security research

The only valid case I can consider, whose validity is debatable, is that of security research (which is my field). When I'm given a possible phishing link, I'm going to anonymize it. This means I'll enter fake data rather than reveal my source. I'd never intentionally go after a subscription mechanism (at least with an email I don't control), but I suppose automation could accidentally stumble into such a thing.

You can avoid that by requiring POST requests to subscribe. No (well-designed) subscription mechanism should accept GET requests or action links without parameters (though there are plenty that do). No (well-designed) web crawler, for search or archiving or security, should generate POST requests, at least without several controls to ensure it's acceptable (such as already concluding that it's a bad actor's site). I'm going to be generous and not call out any security vendors that I know do this.